# Do Indian farmers have the equivalent of a political lobby?

Tags: india, lobbying, agriculture

There are many accusations going around about the recent laws regarding agriculture in India. In particular that these laws are [heavily influenced by corporate interests](https://www.aljazeera.com/economy/2021/1/18/bbtwo-of-indias-richest-men-face-ire-over-its-new-farm-laws). But it seems to me that, considering the [relative importance of agriculture in India](http://www.fao.org/india/fao-in-india/india-at-a-glance/en/)¹, that a farming lobby would be more than sufficiently powerful enough to hold its own in this regards. But I can't find any evidence that such a specifically organized coalition exists.

> ¹ <sup><sub>Agriculture, with its allied sectors, is the largest source of livelihoods in India. 70 percent of its rural households still depend primarily on agriculture for their livelihood, with 82 percent of farmers being small and marginal. In 2017-18, total food grain production was estimated at 275 million tonnes (MT).  India is the largest producer (25% of global production), consumer (27% of world consumption) and importer (14%) of pulses in the world. India's annual milk production was 165 MT (2017-18), making India the largest producer of milk, jute and pulses, and with world's second-largest cattle population 190 million in 2012.[153] It is the second-largest producer of rice, wheat, sugarcane, cotton and groundnuts, as well as the second-largest fruit and vegetable producer, accounting for 10.9% and 8.6% of the world fruit and vegetable production, respectively.</sub></sup>

Comment: Please don't use comments to post answers. If you would like to answer the question, please post a real answer which adheres to our quality standards.